# git merge doing bad things - how to not auto-merge *anything*

Tags: git, merge

I have searched for and tried various flags to perform a merge, but everything I try results in the merged code missing a class that's used in the merged code.  Specifically, I have a python exception class at the bottom of a file in my feature branch.  I do a merge with main, and I have 5 files with conflicts.  When I go in to resolve the conflicts, the exception class (`TypeUnitsMismatch`) that is supposed to be at the bottom of the file (as it is in the feature branch) is completely missing.  There's not even a diff prompting me to select to keep the incoming/current change or not.  The class is just gone.

How can I perform the merge and have it show me *every* difference (i.e. auto-merge *nothing* and ask me to confirm every change)?

I don't know what caused this issue, but I suppose it's possible a separate branch with a rebase and a force-push could have caused this?

For example, here's the bottom of the file in the feature branch:

```
class UnknownComparison(Exception):
    pass


class TypeUnitsMismatch(Exception):
    def __init__(self, type):
        message = (
            f"Unsupported combination of field type {type} and units.  Only fields of type 'number' can have unit "
            "options."
        )
        super().__init__(message)
        self.type = type
```

And here's the bottom of the file *with* the conflicts I need to resolve *before* me resolving anything:

```
class UnknownComparison(Exception):
    pass
```

What I *want* to see is something like this when I try to merge main into the feature branch:

```
class UnknownComparison(Exception):
    pass


<<<<<<< HEAD
class TypeUnitsMismatch(Exception):
    def __init__(self, type):
        message = (
            f"Unsupported combination of field type {type} and units.  Only fields of type 'number' can have unit "
            "options."
        )
        super().__init__(message)
        self.type = type
=======
>>>>>>> main
```

I've tried merging both directions.  I've tried merging with `--no-ff` and with `--no-commit`.  Nothing results in that desired diff.

I also tried a rebase, but the second or third conflict in that file is nonsense/jibberish with what looks like nested diff annotations.

I was thinking I could just copy all the touched files in the branch to a new branch so that the auto-merge would behave differently, but then I would lose all the commit notes.

How the heck do I ensure I get a correct merge.

Note, this branch is 58 commits behind main.  We had some other work come up that took priority for awhile, so I'd set this work aside for some time.

Comment: You can't get that, but you can get a bit close by declaring the files unmergable (`-merge` or `binary` in `.gitattributes`; note that `binary` is probably way too strong). If you're seeing what look like nested diffs, that suggests that you have a criss-cross merge resulting in an ambiguous merge base, which in turn probably explains the later state: basically, someone wrecked the history, so now when Git goes to do merges, it's getting bad inputs.

Comment: It's very rare to hit this problem but when you do it's a big pain. There are no good resolutions other than to just fix it all up and avoid having someone wreck it again later (find out who did and teach them better).

Comment: can you show us the 3 versions of the code involved in the merge, related to _that_ specific portion of the file? It would be as it is in the 2 branches involved in the merge _and_ in their common ancestor (which can be retrieved with `git merge-base HEAD the-other-branch`)

Comment: Let me just correct my previous comment: on top of the 2 versions you already provided there, also show us the section of the file as it is in the common ancestor.

Comment: I'm not even sure what the common ancestor was.  There was an extra merge applied on top of this feature branch from a commit on an unpushed branch (because I apparently edited a stale branch on my work computer thinking I was on the feature branch I'd started at home, because I'd forgotten the branch name).  How do I find the common ancestor (without manually comparing hashes in the logs of my feature branch and the main one)?

Comment: Oh, I think I see: `git merge-base HEAD main` (from my feature branch)?

Comment: My boss said I could squash all the commits on the feature branch to a single commit.  I haven't used squash before.  How would I do that?

Comment: Wait.  `git merge-base HEAD main` outputs a hash that, before it, there are commits that only exist on this feature branch, so that can't be the common ancestor!

Comment: In fact, I see commits with the same message duplicated with different hashes.  This is so confusing.

Comment: Oh wait!  I remember!  This all perhaps stems from an accidental push to main that wasn't caught for a few days!  And to revert, I'd created a new commit that manually undid those changes, because excising that commit was too disruptive, because other people had pulled those changes.  THAT's what this is all about!

Comment: It must be that "undo" commit that is removing the code in the branch that I'd merged that accidental main commit onto the feature branch.

Comment: git can do _wonderful_ things.... but one it does not is miracles (even if it gets close, sometimes). Your question starts with a complaint about _unexpected_ section of code that is missing and you want to find a way to avoid it from *ever* happening.... for all practical purposes, merging results depend on _input_...  most likely, in the _common ancestor_ (for reasons that you would have to track down), the piece of code _is there_. It is still there in one branch, it is _missing_ in the other... **so** (quite unsurprisingly) the section of code is missing in your merged file.... so....

Comment: ... the question is not about why the piece of code is missing (it is missing because it is expected from input that it be missing).... the question is _why do you have a messed up history_. Provide git with the correct history and you won't be wondering like this.

Comment: Bottom line: merge is not doing **bad things**. It is behaving just as expected.

Comment: I never said git wasn't doing what it is *supposed/designed* to do. I was just trying to figure out how to get it to do what I *wanted* it to do.  I *wanted* it to look at the head of both branches and give me a diff so I could resolve differences when the history was messed up.  I didn't want it to auto-merge anything, and I thought maybe there was a way to do that that I just wasn't aware of. I explicitly asked that in the second paragraph. My Q was incomplete, bec I couldn't remember what happened, so feel free to downvote me.

Comment: "bad things" is relative. In this case it meant, it took a working `main` and a working `feature branch` and merged them in a non-working state. Yes, it's my fault for having accidentally pushed to main. I don't deny that. I just wanted to know what options were available to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

OK, so the question was not constructed terribly well, mainly because I couldn't remember what had happened.  I think this is a rough synopsis of the events that lead to this issue:

1. I started a branch named `units` on October 18th
2. I made an accidental commit & push of some changes to `main` at some point during development (because I was switching back and forth between branches and lost track of where I was)
3. My work on `units` got interrupted by other higher priority work.  A couple weeks pass, in which I and other merge work on other branches to main.  (We had multiple concurrent branches getting merged into main with at one point 7 open PRs, which prompted some of the branches to be rebased before merging into main.)
4. I discovered the accidental push to main and instead of messing with the history, I crafted a custom commit to main that "un-did" the changes of that accidental commit/push
5. I merged those accidental commits/pushes to main into the feature branch where they should have gone in the first place and realized that this would be a mess later when I tried merging that `units` branch and just figured I'd cross that bridge when I came to it - then continued with my other higher-priority work
6. Yesterday, I picked the work on the `units` branch back up and finished it up.  A PR was created and I noted that I had conflicts with main I needed to resolve.
7. Today I tried the rebase/merge and as I often do, had forgotten what the troubles were that brought me here.

To merge, I tried the following, but none of them solved my problem (I tried both directions, but this example is from `units` merging main):

```
git merge --no-ff main  -- The TypeUnitsMismatch class was still missing from the diff
git merge --no-commit main  -- The TypeUnitsMismatch class was still missing from the diff
git merge -s ours main  -- TypeUnitsMismatch was present, but other's novel code in main was removed
```

As my boss suggested, I was able to squash all the commits on the `units` branch down into a single "new" commit.  But `git merge-base HEAD main` was not producing the correct common ancestor and the git log appeared to have duplicate entries with different hashes - possibly due to rebasing or other weird merges from other work?  Luckily, I enter good notes in the commit messages and I was able to walk back and figure out that the last 12 commits contained all the novel code on the `units` branch.  There may have been some common commits in there (with main) due to the complicated path, but it didn't have any negative side-effects.

I squashed those last 12 commits down into a single commit and preserved the commit messages with:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~12
git commit --edit -m"$(git log --format=%B --reverse HEAD..HEAD@{1})"
```

Then when I did a `git merge main`, I only had 1 minor/simple conflict in a CSS file involving 4 lines of code.  I then did a `git diff main` and all the previously missing code was present as new code and all the novel code in main was not showing up as having been removed.  All the linting passes and the tests are currently running, so I'm optimistic everything is good.

### TL;DR

Ultimately, although I was able to address my issues in this case using a squash strategy (albeit losing code changes associated with each individual commit), I don't have an answer to the original question:

**[If my history is messed up,] "How can I perform the merge and have it show me every difference (i.e. auto-merge nothing and ask me to confirm every change) [in a flat manner]?"**

**I.e. Ignore the common ancestor and do a plain diff between the 2 HEADs as a merge option.**

If there was a way to do that, and you have 2 working branches (e.g. my current `main` and `units` branches), such a capability (to manually resolve EVERY difference between the heads of those 2 branches in a flat manner to create a new commit) would be extremely useful.